# Integrating alfresco workdesk with my java app in order to use Activiti based Workflow

Tags: java, alfresco, activiti

my goal is to use alfresco Workdesk workflow functionalities. 
is there related API or Service from which i can call workflow methods
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to define your question in more detail to get a more detailed response.

Workdesk uses the Activiti engie which is integrated into the Alfresco Repository. Thus Workdesk is just a client that consumes Alfresco's Workflow API. You should be able to use this API on your own: http://docs.alfresco.com/4.2/references/RESTful-Workflow.html

Comment: thank you for the reply, but as i mentioned i want to reuse the dynamic way of manipulating process tasks like workdesk does. so my idea was trying to consume some behavior from the existing functionalities of workdesk. What i understood from you, is that no way to do that

Comment: are you sure that workdesk manipluates process tasks? Afaik workdesk just "handles" workflow task: fill in data, rigger transition & Co

Comment: Ok, My goal is to be able to use a tool that integrates with ldap in order to import users and groups to the process. from the documentation i have done , it's alfresco community. am i in the correct path? well my idea is to import users to community and then to activiti in order to use them to manipulate my workflow processes.Other question, can alfresco acitiviti import community users?

Comment: sorry, but I didn't get you. Alfresco Activiti uses "assignees" to assign a task to a person or a group. Once your users/groups are imported via ldap subsystem into Alfresco you can uses them for such purposes.
What exactly do you mean by "manipulate my workflow processes"?

Comment: thx for replying quickly :) i have tested the assignees think with activiti but i could not import community users. is there a config to do? is  alfresco community the subsystem? well manipulating i meant modifying the process(the task role, the nodes, the switch..)

Comment: Alfresco community is "the platform" that uses Activiti as embedded bpm engine. Workdesk is a client for this platform. You can import users & groups from a LDAP by configuring a ldap or ldap-ad subsystem (http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Alfresco_Authentication_Subsystems)
Pls try to re-define your question in more detail + more fine-grained to get a more detailed response.

Comment: I have an app that does the redirecting manually, I mean using flags on database(no use of workflow engine to do that) which the uses are imported from LDAP, what i want to do is to migrate it to an app that uses activiti as bpm. So i want to get rid of  the db redirecting think. coz I want to be able to change process in any time i want. Am I on the correct Path?